# Отваливается сервер Apache при регулярных POST-запросах

Tags: php, ajax, apache, post

Делаю один проект на биржевую тематику. Там требуется через каждые 15 секунд обновлять котировки акций (AJAX). Все работает хорошо, но по прошествии 1-2 часов выскакивает непонятная ошибка:

`PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: _POST in ...`

При этом отваливаются все AJAX-запросы, точнее они проходят, но теперь в них не передается переменная POST (см. ошибку). Эта же ошибка присутствует и у любого другого приложения, запущенного в текущей среде (например, тот же phpmyadmin). При этом GET-запросы обрабатываются.

Через некоторое время падает и сам Apache, после перезагрузки все становится нормально.

Есть подозрение, что идет какое-то переполнение буфера, но там передаются в каждом запросе небольшие данные, так что странно.

У кого есть какие идеи в чем может быть дело и как выяснить точную причину?

Comment: а настройки апача какие? Нагрузка может слишком большая?

Comment: а не проще посмотреть лог апача? Возможно там что-то найдется?

Comment: по логу видны только эти ошибки с POST-переменными. настройки Apache стандартные, нагрузки тоже особой нет. выяснил, что там была ошибка, связанная с отправкой из Node.JS POST-запросов на скрипт PHP, который был настроен на прием GET-запросов. поправил код, посмотрим как себя все поведет сейчас